# how to write inline lambda code with node dependencies?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I created an lambda function from aws console ( see below). it is a simple function returning random number from 5-100. it works. I created the zip file with node_modules and uploaded the file, as it has some dependencies. if i wanted to move this lamda code, which has dependencies to inline cloudformation template, will it be possible?

```
var moment = require('moment');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100- 5+ 1)) + min;
  
  callback(null, randomNumber + ' generated at ' + moment().format());
};
```

cloudformation template

```
Description: learning lambda

  somelambdaexample:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Description: process a signal
      Role: someRole
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
          
          
          };
      Timeout: 30
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bundle your dependencies with lambda, you have two options:

1. Create a **deployment package** with the [dependencies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-package.html#nodejs-package-dependencies), and upload it to S3. Then in the CloudFormation, you can [specify](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-function-code.html) `S3Bucket` and `S3Key` of the package in S3.
2. Or create [AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-layerversion.html) with your dependencies. Then in your lambda function template, you can link to the layer using [Layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html#cfn-lambda-function-layers) property. Using layers will allow you to **inline your function code** using `Code: ZipFile` as you are doing now.

So, to answer your question:

> if i wanted to move this lamda code, which has dependencies to inline cloudformation template, will it be possible?

Yes, **its possible** using layers.

Comment: -I appreciate it. if it is not too much trouble, could you point me to any examples/samples that you might have come across.

Comment: did you find any examples?

Comment: AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion does Not support "Code: ZipFile" (following your link)